# Finding points close together

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geoprocessing

I am using ArcGIS desktop. I want to run a tool to find all points that are close to each other within a specific distance.

What is the fastest and best tool to use?
I am using the standard arcgis with the Spatial Analyst extension.

Comment: Near (Analysis) Toolbox http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00080000001q000000

Comment: @Mapperz According to the documentation, each point is associated only with its closest neighbor: that does not solve this problem, which seeks *all* points within a given distance. Is there perhaps some other mode in which `Near (Analysis)` works that does solve this problem?

Comment: Near has a {location} & {search_radius} parameter that can be used, which is optional.

Comment: Point Distance tool does not allow the X,Y coordinates to be written. But it is almost identical code in ArcGIS to Near.

Answer (score 4):

To do this I would use the **[Point Distance](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000001r000000)** tool which:

> Determines the distances from input point features to all points in
>   the near features within a specified search radius.

Answer (score 1):

The best way for points if you have a large number is to use the geohash module for Python. This is hundreds of times faster than Near and very flexible. But if you only have a few, just use Near.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash

```
import Geohash
# .... make a dictionary of the point coordinates
for row in arcpy.SearchCursor(inputFC):
            d[row.getValue(pk)] = [row.getValue(keyatt),
                                   Geohash.encode((row.shape.firstPoint.Y),(row.shape.firstPoint.X),precision=10)]
# ... compare the dictionaries, if they are the same geohash they are within the same tolerance.
def valuesChanged(dict1, dict2,sBoth):
    '''get a list of keys from one dict if a corresponding dict's values are different'''
    outList = [key for key in sBoth if dict1.get(key) != dict2.get(key)]
    return outList
```

Comment: The document cited recommends examining the 8 surrounding geohashes to be a robust proximity search.